# How do I carry forward variable values in WinForms?

Tags: winforms, button

I'm trying to make it so that there is a total at the bottom depending on what buttons are pressed (when I hit the 'calculate' button).  If button 1 is pressed, it shows 30 points, if button 2, it shows 60 points, if button 3 is pressed, it shows 90 points.  But any or all of them can be pressed, so if 1 and 3 are pressed, it shows 120.

I know that there is some way to carry forward the value of a variable, but I can't think of it or find it (I'm very new at this).  I'm also not sure if 'if' statements are the best way to handle this (especially if I end up having 25 or so buttons), so if there is a better way, please let me know.

(I have it so that the button turns lime green if pressed.)

```
int score1 = 0;

        if (button1.BackColor == Color.Lime)
        {
            label10.Text = (30 + score1).ToString();
        }
        else label10.Text = score1.ToString();

        if (button2.BackColor == Color.Lime)
        {
            label10.Text = (60 + score1).ToString();
        }
        else label10.Text = score1.ToString();

        if (button3.BackColor == Color.Lime)
        {
            label10.Text = (90 + score1).ToString();
        }
        else label10.Text = score1.ToString();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code, namely the method that contains the code you have already posted? And why are you checking the button's color to do an action rather than using the associated OnClick event?

Comment: Yep, an OnClick event would be better, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to add a form variable in your class to hold the running total:

```
private int totalScore = 0;
```

You can have a method to set the background color and add to the score:

```
private void SetBackgroundAndAddToTotal(Button button, int score)
{
    if (button.BackColor != Color.Lime)
    {
        button.BackColor = Color.Lime;
        this.totalScore = this.totalScore + score;
    }
}
```

Inside the `Click` handler for each button that needs to affect the total, you can call `SetBackgroundAndAddToTotal()`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetBackgroundAndAddToTotal(button1, 30);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetBackgroundAndAddToTotal(button2, 60);
}

// etc.
```

Then, in your click handler for your "Calculate" button, you can just grab the already-calculated total from the form variable and display it:

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label10.Text = this.totalScore.ToString();
}
```

Would that work?

Comment: Ah Ha!  It's the 'this.x = this.x +y;'  that I couldn't remember.

Thanks for that, and the rest too!